# Как запустить консоль Linux с alias-аргументом?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, shell

Как запустить консоль Linux с аргументом alias?

К примеру, в Windows: `start cmd /k doskey p3=C:\Python34\python.exe`.

Comment: в linux этого делать не надо, ваши  alias-ы прочтутся из файликов инициалиазации, например ~/.bashrc.

Comment: @0xdb Язнаю о наличии `.bashrc` файле. Но мне надо запустить командную строку с аргументом(-ами).

Comment: А что значит - консоль Linux? Уточните вопрос, где и что вы собираетесь запустить в командной строке?

Answer (score 4):

Прямого аналога `start cmd /k doskey p3=C:\Python34\python.exe` в *linux* нет.

В *linux* имеется 6-ть текстовых консолей, которые запускаются системно при старте. Запустить, как указано в вопросе, можно новое окно эмулятора терминала, а не текстовую консоль. Такие детали, как - удалённо, локально, X - я в этом ответе не рассматриваю.

Судя по всему, в вопросе имеется ввиду следующее:

Из текущего командного интерпретатора (или командной строки в текущем окне терминала):

- `start cmd` - запустить новый командный интерпретатор в новом окне
- `/k doskey p3=C:\Python34\python.exe` - запустить там
  команду, и после её завершения не покидать новый интерпретатор, т.е. остаться в новом окне.

В linux вместо `start` можно статртовать новый эмулятор терминала. Для примера взял `mintty` с параметром `--exec`, в других подобных программах (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, `konsole` и т.п.) примерно то же самое (`--execute, --command`).

В терминале будет запущен командный интерпретер (`shell`), в большинстве случаев это `bash`. Аналога `/k command` в нём нет, а с близким по смыслу `-c command` он выполнит команду и завершиться. Но можно с опцией `--rcfile` изменить инициализацию, добавив необходимые команды.

В первом окне:

```
mintty --exec bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; alias pt2=/usr/bin/python2.7') &
```

Во вновь открывшемся окне:

```
~$ pt2 --version
Python 2.7.13
~$ type pt2
pt2 is aliased to `/usr/bin/python2.7'
```

Если, как указано в вопросе, интересна текстовая консоль, это решение будет также работать, если есть возможность из неё запустить новое окно терминала.

А самое простое решение остаётся - прописывать все необходимые команды в `.bashrc` и с помощью `if ... else` управлять, что запускать в определённой среде, а что нет.